# simplify this formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm attempting to simplify this formula for when r is equal to
$$
\frac{119}{2\sin(θ/2)+2(π-θ)/2}
$$
the formula is:

$$A = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2} (θ-\sinθ) r^2$$

I've tried but i'm confused particularly about the fact that you end up with a fraction in a fraction. Overall, my aim is to make θ the only variable so i can find the maximum by finding its derivative and making the equation equal 0.

Ps. sorry if my brackets are 100% correct :)

Comment: So you mean to calculate $\frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta}$ and then want to solve for the value of $\theta$ so that $\frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta} = 0$ ? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @MattiP. Exactly!

Comment: If you don't want to plug $r$ into the equation you could just the chain rule and calculate
$$
\frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial r} \cdot \frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta} 
$$ Just offering an option ...

Comment: Following up on @MattiP.'s suggestion, when you compute $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$, you'll see that you can pull out a factor of $r$, which gives you a factor of $r^2$ in $\frac{dA}{d\theta}$ Since $r\neq0$, this will give you a (messy) equation in $\theta$ alone.

Comment: Why is this tagged algebra-precalculus?  In what precalculus class do you learn about the chain rule?

Comment: @saulspatz, it's the unit i'm currently studying and this is an element of a question we were asked.

Comment: @MattiP. how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I can do the differentiation for you. Let's do it in small steps and using the chain rule. First we have
$$
r(\theta) = \frac{119}{2\sin(θ/2)+\pi-\theta}  = \frac{119}{g(\theta)}
$$
I re-named the denominator as $g(\theta)$ to simplify the notation. The derivative of $r$ with respect to $\theta$ is now
$$
r'(\theta) = -\frac{g'(\theta)}{g(\theta)^2}
$$
The derivative of $g$ is relatively easy to compute, it's just
$$
g(\theta) = 2\sin \frac{\theta}{2} + \pi - \theta \quad \Rightarrow \quad
g'(\theta) = \cos \frac{\theta}{2} -1 
$$
Therefore, we have the intermediate result
$$
r'(\theta) = -119 \frac{\cos \frac{\theta}{2} -1 }{ \left( 2\sin \frac{\theta}{2} + \pi - \theta \right)^2}
$$
(It looks like the whole derivative expression will be quite complicated!)
Now we can calculate the derivative of $A$ with respect to $\theta$, using the chain rule and product rule!
$$A = \underbrace{\frac{\pi r(\theta)^2}{2}}_{=B(\theta)} + \underbrace{\frac{-1}{2} (θ-\sinθ)}_{=C(\theta)} \underbrace{r(\theta)^2}_{=D(\theta)} = B(\theta)+C(\theta)D(\theta)$$
$$
\begin{split}
A'(\theta) &= B'(\theta) &+ C'(\theta)\cdot D(\theta) &+ C(\theta) \cdot D'(\theta)\\
&= r'(\theta)\cdot \pi r(\theta) &+ \frac{-1}{2}(1-\cos \theta)\cdot r (\theta)^2
&+ \frac{-1}{2} (θ-\sinθ)\cdot 2 r (\theta) 
\end{split}
$$
We can still take $r(\theta)$ as a common factor to get
$$
A'(\theta) = \left[ \pi r'(\theta)  - \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos \theta)r (\theta)
- θ+\sinθ) \right] r(\theta)
$$
Now you just need to plug in the expressions for $r(\theta)$ and $r'(\theta)$ ...
$$
A'(\theta) = \left[ -119 \pi \frac{\cos \frac{\theta}{2} -1 }{ \left( 2\sin \frac{\theta}{2} + \pi - \theta \right)^2}  - \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos \theta)\frac{119}{2\sin(θ/2)+\pi-\theta}
- θ+\sinθ) \right] \frac{119}{2\sin(θ/2)+\pi-\theta}
$$

Answer (score 0):

To make things slightly less messy, let's write $\phi=\pi-\theta.$  Then $$r=\frac{119}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi-\phi}{2}\right)+\phi}=\frac{119}{\cos\frac\phi2+\phi}$$ and $$A=\frac{r^2}2(\phi+\sin \phi)$$
Now $$\frac{dr}{d\phi}=
\frac{-119}{\left(\cos\frac\phi2+\phi\right)^2}\left(1-\sin \frac\phi2\right)=r\frac{\sin\frac\phi2-1}{\phi+2\cos\frac\phi2}$$ abd by implicit differentiation, $$\begin{align}
\frac{dA}{d\phi}&=r(\phi+\sin\phi)\frac{dr}{d\phi}+\frac{r^2}{2}(1+\cos\phi)\\
&=r^2(\phi+\sin\phi)\frac{\sin\frac\phi2-1}{\phi+2\cos\frac\phi2}+\frac{r^2}{2}(1+\cos\phi)\\
\end{align}$$
Since $r^2\neq0$, $$\frac{dA}{d\phi=0}\iff(\phi+\sin\phi)\frac{\sin\frac\phi2-1}{\phi+2\cos\frac\phi2}+\frac12(1+\cos\phi)=0$$ and clearing denominators, this last is equivalent to
$$(\phi+\sin\phi)\left(\sin\frac\phi2-1\right)+\frac12(1+\cos\phi)\left(\phi+2\cos\frac\phi2\right)=0$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2Bsin%20x%29%20%28sin%28x%2F2%29-1%29%2B%281%2B%20cos%20x%29%28x%20%2B2%20cos%28x%2F2%29%29%3D0) finds many solutions to this equation, including one at $\phi=\pi,$ or $\theta=0,$  You haven't given any bounds on $\theta$ in the question, so I don't know how to carry on from here.

In the above, I have ignored the possibility that the derivatives don't exist, which will happen if $\phi+\cos\frac\phi2=0$.  [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2B2cos%28x%2F2%29%3D0) finds one solution to this equation at $$\phi\approx-1.47817$$ or $\theta=\pi+1.47817$.  If this is in the range you are interested in, you also have to consider the value of $A$ at this point.  Also, if $\theta$ is restricted to a finite interval, don't forget to check the endpoints.